How to generate an annual return (performance) table of several securities accounts in Excel
I have a data set which consists of the following structure and would like to generate an annual return table. Data can be for only first day of each year, or sometimes monthly intervals as well. For the current year, the performance should be shown as YTD (see details below). Is there an elegant way to do this as my data set has 8500 rows. Personally, I was thinking about creating a filter first to get a range of only the data for the relevant period for the specific account. And then applying a calculation (using MIN and MAX on the date to select the right value row) to determine whether you need only to calculate the performance over a whole year or year to date.
The formula to calculate the return is just (1/1/18 - 1/1/17)/(1/1/17). When we are in the current year, e.g 2024 in the month of June, we take the value of 1/6/24 as the value of 1/1/25 is yet unknown.
For this example, I took the value of 1/1/21 for both accounts as 20000 (hence the big return).
But I was wondering if there is a suggested or elegant way to do this and keep calculations as low as possible?



Date
Account
Value




01/01/2017
Account 1
1000


01/01/2018
Account 1
1203


01/01/2019
Account 1
1242


01/01/2017
Account 2
2000


01/01/2018
Account 2
3181


01/01/2019
Account 2
3395


01/01/2020
Account 1
2858


01/02/2020
Account 1
4653


01/03/2020
Account 1
4949


01/04/2020
Account 1
6515


01/05/2020
Account 1
7449


01/06/2020
Account 1
9126


01/07/2020
Account 1
9346


01/08/2020
Account 1
9564


01/09/2020
Account 1
10230


01/10/2020
Account 1
11021


01/11/2020
Account 1
12780


01/12/2020
Account 1
14249


01/01/2020
Account 2
5217


01/02/2020
Account 2
5626







2017
2018
2019
2020




Account 1
20,30%
3,24%
130,11%
599,79%


Account 2
59,05%
6,72%
53,66%
283,36%



Updated formatting and some details on the return calculation

Could you share some relevant sample data using this Table to Markdown Generator so we have something to work with? Simply copy not more than 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of a table into the website's text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question).
The logic of how you got the data in the 2nd table is unclear. You forgot to share the formula(s) you have tried. Please add the additional information to your post.

Please explain the math behind the values you show for results. For Account 1, you show value for 1/1/2017 of 1.000  and for 1/1/2018 a value of 1.820. I don't understand how this computes to an annual return of 36% when your value has increase 82% over the year.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Complex formulas and/or helper columns can be used to implement this algorithm, but, for me, it seems simpler to accomplish using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

M Code
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Returns"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Account", type text}, {"Value", type number}}),

//Add the relevant year to the data set
    #"Added Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Year", each Date.Year([Date]), Int64.Type),

//Calculate the appreciation for each year
    #"Added Appreciation" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Year", "Appreciation", (t)=> 
        let 

//The "Start" value will always be the first value in that year
//we ASSUME the yearly entries are in ascending date order for each account
//  else we will need a sort or a lookup
            firstYear = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Year", each 
                    t[Year] = [Year] 
                     and t[Account] = [Account]),
            Start = firstYear[Value]{0},

//"End" value -- if there is a subsequent year, then use the first entry in that year
//     else use the last entry in the current year
            End = try Table.SelectRows(#"Added Year", each 
                        t[Year]+1 = [Year] 
                        and t[Account] = [Account])[Value]{0}
                  otherwise List.Last(firstYear[Value]),
            Apprec = (End-Start)/Start
        in 
            Apprec, Percentage.Type),
    
//remove no longer required columns and Pivot the results for each Account by year
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Appreciation",{"Date", "Value"}),
    #"Pivot Headers" = List.Transform(List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Year])),each Text.From(_)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Account"}, {
        {"Pivot", (t)=>
                    let 
                        #"Transform Header Col" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(t,{{"Year", type text}}),
                        Headers = List.Transform(List.Sort(List.Distinct(t[Year])), each Text.From(_)),
                        pivot= Table.Pivot(#"Transform Header Col", Headers,"Year", "Appreciation", List.Median)
                    in 
                        pivot,
                        type table 
                            fnRecordTypes(#"Pivot Headers", List.Repeat({Percentage.Type},List.Count(#"Pivot Headers")))
                        }}),
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Pivot", #"Pivot Headers")
in
    #"Expanded Pivot"


